# How to allow Å Ä Ö & å ä ö inside the textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I want allow user to type only alphabet ,space and Å Ä Ö & å ä ö the given character in Text Box.
alphabet validation and space is working fine but what I have to do for this character Å Ä Ö & å ä ö

Now I am using below `javascript` function,

```js
 function ValidateAlpha(evt) {
debugger;
evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
if (charCode != 13 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 37 || charCode > 40) && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122) && (charCode == 196 || charCode == 142))
{
swal("Enter Only Character");
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude or allow specific characters, you would have to explicitly state which ones.

You can use [this web page](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/capital-letter-a-ring-uppercase-ascii-code-143.html) to see which character code belongs to each character.

As you can see in this page, the characters you mention are between `128` and `165`.

So to allow these characters, just add:

```
((charCode > 128) && (charCode < 165))
```

**Recommendation**:

To exclude all non-English characters, you can replace your whole condition with this simple one:

```
if (charCode > 126)
{
    swal("Enter Only Character");
    return false;
}
```

To exclude all non-English characters and allow `Å Ä Ö å ä ö`:

```
if ((charCode >  128) && 
    (charCode != 134) && 
    (charCode != 142) && 
    (charCode != 143) && 
    (charCode != 153) && 
    (charCode != 199) && 
    (charCode != 198))
{
    swal("Enter Only Character");
    return false;
}
```